# Como enviar um objeto entre controllers através do Redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

***Como enviar um Objeto através do redirect entre requests?***

Realizei testes tentando enviar o objeto através do model, porém sem sucesso.

Segue o código:

```
 @RequestMapping("removeResultado")
 public String remove(RequestParam(value = "codigo", required = true)int cod,Model model) {
  Evento evento = daoEvento.buscarIDEvento(cod);
  model.addAttribute(evento);
  this.dao.remove(cod);
  return "redirect:listaResultados";
 }


 @RequestMapping("listaResultados")
 public String busca(Evento evento, Model model) {
  List<Resultado> resultados = this.dao.buscaResultadosEvento(evento);
  model.addAttribute("resultados", resultados);
  return  "/Resultado/ListaResultados";
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o [RedirectAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) para poder passar os objetos pelo `redirect`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/suaUrl", method=GET)
public String seuMetodo(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
{
   ...
   redirectAttributes.addAttribute("mensagem", "redirecionamento");
   redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("objeto2", objeto2);
   return "redirect:/outraUrl";
}
```

Quando se usa o  `addAttribute` eles são utilizados para construir uma nova URL de redirecionamento, com isso o uso se limita a primitivos e a String.

E quando você usa o `addFlashAttribute` os dados são guardados(geralmente na sessão) temporariamente e estão disponíveis para solicitação e após o redirecionamento são removidas. A vantagem é que você pode adicionar qualquer objeto.

[Resposta original em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266427/what-are-ways-for-pass-parameters-from-controller-after-redirect-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Excelente, o addFlashAttribute acho que seria a melhor solução.

Comment: @Matheus faz o teste, caso ocorra algum problema me avisa que te ajudo.